# How to calculate exponentially weighted standard deviation in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with daily time series for 2 years. I want to exponentially weight that time series (alpha of 0.05) and then calculate its standard deviation, which I then compare to the non-weighted standard deviation.

This is what I'm currently doing,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = np.random.normal(0, 2, 500)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Value'])

alpha = 0.054
df['EWMSTD'] = df['Value'].ewm(alpha=alpha).std()

std_dev = df['Value'].std()
```

Ultimately what I need to do is compare the regular standard deviation (`std_dev` in above code) to an exponentially weighted one.

So expected output will be something like this,

```
Std dev is ABC
Exp std dev is XYZ
```

What I don't understand is how the EWMSTD column is calculated as I don't specify a rolling/moving window. I'd have expected the EWMSTD to be a single number rather than a column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*I'd have expected the EWMSTD to be a single number rather than a column*"

As stated by the **M** the name, an EW**M**A ([Exponentially Weighted **Moving** Average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average)), is a **rolling** function.

This outputs as many values as its inputs.

Also see the examples in [`pandas.DataFrame.ewm`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html).

###### previous answer

What you expect is not fully clear, but I believe you can use `halflife` directly, passing your date column as `time`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2023-01-01', '2025-12-31', freq='D'),
                   'value': range(1096)
                  })
df['ewm_std'] = df['value'].ewm(halflife='182D', times=df['date']).std()
```

Output:

```
           date  value   ewm_std
0    2023-01-01      0       NaN
1    2023-01-02      1  0.707107
2    2023-01-03      2  0.963624
3    2023-01-04      3  1.177164
4    2023-01-05      4  1.345243
...         ...    ...       ...
1091 2025-12-27   1091  1.732051
1092 2025-12-28   1092  1.732051
1093 2025-12-29   1093  1.732051
1094 2025-12-30   1094  1.732051
1095 2025-12-31   1095  1.732051

[1096 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comparison with a rolling `std`:

```
df['ewm_roll'] = df.rolling('182D', on='date')['value'].std()

           date  value   ewm_std   ewm_roll
0    2023-01-01      0       NaN        NaN
1    2023-01-02      1  0.707107   0.707107
2    2023-01-03      2  0.963624   1.000000
3    2023-01-04      3  1.177164   1.290994
4    2023-01-05      4  1.345243   1.581139
...         ...    ...       ...        ...
1091 2025-12-27   1091  1.732051  52.683014
1092 2025-12-28   1092  1.732051  52.683014
1093 2025-12-29   1093  1.732051  52.683014
1094 2025-12-30   1094  1.732051  52.683014
1095 2025-12-31   1095  1.732051  52.683014

[1096 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: Sorry about not being clear, was quite late when I posted the question. I am using alpha rather than halflife, and I have corrected the code above. There is no moving/rolling element to what I'm doing. I just want to compare the normal and exponentially weighted standard deviation for a fixed/static window.

Comment: @insomniac then please clarify the expected output

Comment: The expected output will be a (regular) standard deviation calculation, and a weighted standard deviation. So in total just two numbers. So what's confusing me is to how to get the weighted standard deviation from pandas given the alpha.

Comment: @insomniac I meant, provide a meaningful [mre] with the matching expected output

Comment: I have edited the original question. I hope it's a bit clearer now.

Comment: @insomniac I see, and thus you're probably not looking for an EWMA (see my update) ;)